# tkzinc bbox command taking hours to complete

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, xorg

I have tcl script for creating tkzinc canvas which have multiple compartments and other components associated with each compartment.

The code runs perfectly fine with 32-bit centos5.6 and takes less than a minute but on 64-bit centos7 it takes around **25-28 hours** load the canvas.

Need help on the same.

Comment: How many canvas items are we talking here?

Comment: Somewhere around 1000

Comment: What are the versions of tcl/tk on the two systems?

Comment: A thousand items shouldn't really take that long. I'd expect even millions to only take a short amount of time, _at least with standard canvas items_ (I've used them to plot some pretty complex graphs even back around 20 years ago). Something nasty is going on.

Comment: It might be worth reporting this as a bug. The development appears to be on [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/plecoanet/tkzinc) so that's where to start looking for a way to report a problem.

Comment: @BradLanam: I am using tcl/tk 8.5

Comment: @DonalFellows: Exactly my point , because the same code runs perfectly fine in 32-bit Centos5.6.